# Accessing static member class

Tags: java, nested-class

I learnt that, to access the static member class, the syntax is `OuterClass.NestedStaticClass`.

For the given below interface `Input`,

```
interface Input{

    static class KeyEvent{
        public static final int KEY_DOWN = 0;
        public static final int KEY_UP = 0;
        public int type;
        public int keyCode;
        public int keyChar;
    }

    static class TouchEvent{
        public static final int TOUCH_DOWN = 0;
        public static final int TOUCH_UP =0;
        public static final int TOUCH_DRAGGED = 2;
        public int type;
        public int x, y;
        public int pointer;
    }

    public boolean isKeyPressed(int keyCode);
    .....
    public List<KeyEvent> getKeyEvents();
    public List<TouchEvent> getTouchEvents(); 
}
```

below is the implementation `Keyboard`,

```
class Keyboard implements Input{

    ....

    @Override
    public List<TouchEvent> getTouchEvents() {
        TouchEvent obj1 = new TouchEvent();
        TouchEvent obj2 = new TouchEvent();
        List<TouchEvent> list = new ArrayList<TouchEvent>();
        list.add(obj1);
        list.add(obj2);
        return list;
    }

}
```

In this implementation `Keyboard`, I did not require to use `Input.TouchEvent` for below lines of code.

```
TouchEvent obj1 = new TouchEvent();
TouchEvent obj2 = new TouchEvent();
List<TouchEvent> list = new ArrayList<TouchEvent>();
```

But for the below implementation, I had to use `Input.TouchEvent`,

```
public class NestedClassInInterface {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Input.TouchEvent t = new Input.TouchEvent();
    }
}
```

How do I understand this?

Comment: Because you are implementing the Interface `input` in your previous case..

Comment: If you implement the interface `Input`, how is the scope of accessing `KeyEvent` different?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the Java Language Specification, [concerning members of an interface type](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-9.html#jls-9.1.4)

> The body of an interface may declare members of the interface, that
>   is, fields (§9.3), methods (§9.4), classes (§9.5), and interfaces
>   (§9.5).

and concerning the [scope of a declaration](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.3)

> The scope of a declaration of a member `m` declared in or inherited by a
>   class type `C` (§8.1.6) is the entire body of `C`, including any nested
>   type declarations.

and [concerning class members](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.2)

> The members of a class type are all of the following:
>
> - [..]
> - Members inherited from any direct superinterfaces (§8.1.5)

So, the type `TouchEvent` is declared in the type `Input`. It is a member of `Input`. `Keyboard` implements `Input` and therefore inherits its members. `TouchEvent` is therefore in scope in the body of `Keyboard`. You therefore don't need to qualify its use with its enclosing type.

Comment: @overexchange I think you're misreading that. In that quote, `m` is the `TouchEvent` type, `C` is `Keyboard`. _any nested type_ refers to a member class declared within `C`, not `TouchEvent`. In other words, if `Keyboard` had a nested class, the body of the nested class would also be able to use the simple name `TouchEvent`, because it would be in scope.

Answer (score 0):

Quoted from [doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html):

> The scope (§6.3) of a member (§8.2) is the entire body of the
>   declaration of the class to which the member belongs. Field, method,
>   member class, member interface, and constructor declarations may
>   include the access modifiers (§6.6) public, protected, or private. **The
>   members of a class include both declared and inherited members** (§8.2)

So it means class `Keyboard` also has members of `Input` in its scope and can access them directly.

As your class `Keyboard` implements interface `Input` it means `Keyboard` **is** `Input`. And it will be able to access the static nested class directly without using reference of outer interface. All interface fields are also static by default but an implementation class can access them directly.

But when you try to access it in `NestedClassInInterface` (which is not `Input`) it needs reference of outer class/interface which is `Input` in this case. You can try removing `implements Input` from declaration of `Keyboard` and will see what I mean.

Comment: `Keyboard` is `Input` when `class Keyboard extends Input`

Comment: @overexchange: `Input` is an interface here.

Comment: @overexchange The `is` relation works when a class implement an interface as well.

Comment: @overexchange You may have a point about the terminology (is this an "is-a" relationship or not?), but it doesn't matter as far as the scoping rules are concerned.  They're basically the same for `extends` and `implements`.

Comment: @overexchange: If you have a class `Horse` that implements the interface `Animal` Then the Horse IS A animal.